# how long after death can a body exhibit an immune response

Tags: human-biology, death

I suppose this is part of a larger question - at what point do the body's coordinated systems (Endocrine, Autonomic nervous system etc) begin to fail? Within hours? Days? Minutes?

Of course this must vary widely with the means of death but let's assume for the moment a sudden brain embolism or some such that would leave the organs intact.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7548/in-humans-what-is-the-last-metabolic-process-to-cease-after-death?rq=1).